# Does MathJax cache SVG content?

Tags: svg, latex, mathjax, tex

I have extracted LaTeX content from **.tex** file, that I put on the website and choose **SVG** as output, because it provides the smallest possible size so I consider that It will be the best choise also because of his speed and widest versatility. I know, that **.js** files that contains **configurations** are cached on the disk in the browser for a few days (depends on the config of the web) or CDN file, but there could be problem with availability of that page, but what about **SVG content?**

**Does it also cache on the disc?**

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no, depending on what you mean.

For the SVG output, MathJax encodes its "fonts" as path data in JS files, [see the code](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/blob/master/unpacked/jax/output/SVG/fonts/TeX/Math/Italic/Main.js). These paths are cached like any other resource.

But the actual output is generated on the fly from these paths, so the individual equations will not be cached (because making MathJax aware of them would be difficult).

They are stable enough to be reused though, i.e. via local storage and you can generate SVG  server side using MathJax-node.